# R Shiny - Can't generate a PDF anoymore since packages were upgraded

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I upgraded 'by mistake' some of my packages for my shiny app. It was a mistake because my app wouldn't run anymore for some and different reasons. I downgraded the main packages, especially ggplot2 who was very problematic. My app works again but now I can't generate a PDF from a Sweave file in the shiny app.

In the log, there's an error which states that the 'tinytex' package is missing. It's weird because I never had to use this package until now. I installed it and now it says the following error :

```
Warning: Error in tinytex::latexmk: argument unused (encoding = UTF-8)
[No stack trace available]
```

I'm using knitr and I have always used knitr. I specify that the report is in a Sweave file.

I think that the problem is an or some upgrade(s) of package(s). I haven't changed anything except upgrade some packages.

Thanks a lot for your responses.

Comment: `tinytex` is one "distribution" of latex used to render into PDF. Other distributions include LiveTeX and MiKTeX, depending on your OS, only one is required. If you don't know if you have one of these installed, check however your OS allows you (windows: programs/app; linux: apt or yum or ...; macos: brew?), or just install it with `install.packages("tinytex")`. BTW: perhaps it should be `UTF-8`, not `UFT-8`.

Comment: I just installed MiKTeX and the error is still here. I also installed tinytex with your function and it gives the same error. I used the following code `knitr::knit2pdf(input="my_report.Rnw",encoding = "UTF-8",clean=TRUE)`

Comment: Does `tinytex:::is_tinytex()` return true? You might need to restart R and/or RStudio.

Comment: It returns FALSE, you were right. I will reinstall MiKTeX to see what will happen. In an other way, I insist that before I didn't have to use tinytex. I would like to use knitr again if I can.

Comment: `tinytex:::is_tinytex()` return true now, but I still have `Warning: Error in tinytex::latexmk: argument unused (encoding = UTF-8)`

Comment: `tinytest::is_tinytex` returning false indicates that the tinytex installation failed, it was interrupted, or you didn't restart R (and/or RStudio) after installing it (a step I've found necessary ... anecdotally). Looking at the [`latexmk` source](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/blob/b92fa91314a845e8f1aca7a066221ff8b67fc5a1/R/latex.R), there's no indication of `encoding="UTF-8"`. Can you provide the output from `sessionInfo()` as well as a small reproducible report that produces the error? (including how you are rendering it)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's not perfect but if someone has the same error, they can try what I've done.

I can't explain it but when I copy-paste my code in another script file.R (word for word), it seems to work. I progressively copy-paste all the code (ui.R, server.R, myreport.Rnw) in another scripts in a new folder and it finally works.

Also, another mystery, I had to rename my app's folder in shiny-server since it doesn't work with the previous name. Everything works now!